# Prawn using a pdf template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I want to generate a document with prawn that uses a PDF template.

I get no errors, but the template is completely ignored. Does anyone know why this might be? I would really appreciate any help!

```
class JobPdf < Prawn::Document

def initialize(job)
  super()
  @job = job
  text @job.title
  text @job.target_text
end

def render(job)
  doc = Prawn::Document.new({template: "#{Rails.root}/app/templates/jobs/layout.pdf"})
  doc.text job.title
  doc.text job.target_text
  doc.render
end
```

end

Jobs Controller:

```
 def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      pdf = JobPdf.new(@job)
      send_data pdf.render(@job),
      filename: "job#{@job.id}.pdf",
      type: "application/pdf",
      disposition: "inline"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I cannot find any reference regarding a `template` option for the [Document initialize method](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/1.2/Prawn/Document.html#initialize-instance_method). Are you sure that is how you should use it? In fact, the entire page I linked does not really talk about any templates, other than one about page number wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Prawn` has removed templates from its core apparently it is possible to use https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-templates to still utilize them but note even prawn states that this is "very buggy"

Comment: Hey thank you! I'll go look for another way to create pdfs with headers.

Comment: I can confirm that the prawn-templates gem works for simple use cases with prawn 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial, to perform such a task:

http://adamalbrecht.com/2014/01/31/pre-filling-pdf-form-templates-in-ruby-on-rails-with-pdftk/

But in order to make it work you have to use PDFtk besides Rails.